# Error when working with kivymd "AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'"

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I know that this question has probably already been asked many times, but I have a slightly different style structure. I am trying to write a dynamic 3D Card to a dynamic Tab by id, but an error comes out.

Here is a piece of KivyMD style:

```
<Tab>
    ScrollView:
        MDBoxLayout:
            id: tab_box
            orientation: "vertical"      
            adaptive_size: True
            spacing: "56dp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}   
         
        
<MD3Card>
    padding: 4
    size_hint: None, None
    size: "200dp", "100dp"
    MDLabel:
        id: card_label
        text: root.text
        adaptive_size: True
        color: "grey"
        pos: "12dp", "12dp"
        bold: True
```

Here is a piece of code that should, by choosing a certain section in Tab, output certain data, for example, news in MD3Card as a list:

```
def on_tab_switch(
        self, instance_tabs, instance_tab, instance_tab_label, tab_text
):
    '''Called when switching tabs.

    :type instance_tabs: <kivymd.uix.tab.MDTabs object>;
    :param instance_tab: <__main__.Tab object>;
    :param instance_tab_label: <kivymd.uix.tab.MDTabsLabel object>;
    :param tab_text: text or name icon of tab;
    '''
    if tab_text == "section name":
        newss = ["news1", "news2", "news3", "news4", "news5"]
        for news in newss:
            self.root.ids.tab_box.add_widget(
                MD3Card(
                    text=news
                )
            )
```

This code cannot refer to the id that is inside the Tab.

An error comes out:

```
File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 961, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'tab_box'

"AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'"
```

I would like to get a list with information inside Scroll when clicking on a section in Tab without using List and when clicking on any of the news, go to the information with this news already. I saw a solution with ObjectProperty(), but I didn't understand where to enter it, the same error was everywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code snippet:

```
if tab_text == "section name":
    newss = ["news1", "news2", "news3", "news4", "news5"]
    for news in newss:
        self.root.ids.tab_box.add_widget(
            MD3Card(
               text=news
            )
        )
```

Replace with:

```
if tab_text == "section name":
    instance_tab.ids.tab_box.clear_widgets()
    newss = ["news1", "news2", "news3", "news4", "news5"]
    for news in newss:
        instance_tab.ids.tab_box.add_widget(
            MD3Card(
               text=news
            )
        )
```